# How to Handle Large Files in GitHub And Still Allow For AppVeyor Builds

Tags: c#, unit-testing, github, visual-studio-2015, appveyor

GitHub has a limit on how large a file can be.  I have an open source GitHub project that has a several 120mb files that will be required for unit testing... How do I store these files so that AppVeyor and other developers can access these files?

Comment: That is what GitHub LFS is for, is it not? https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.6/admin/articles/configuring-git-large-file-storage-for-a-repository/

Comment: @VonC I'm not using an Enterprise GitHub account.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: No: LFS is also available for github.com (within limits): https://help.github.com/articles/collaboration-with-git-large-file-storage/

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the kind of volumes actually manipulated, you could consider [GitHub LFS](https://help.github.com/articles/collaboration-with-git-large-file-storage/) (available on GitHub.com)

There are storage limits and bandwidth quota though, which might trigger some [billing plans  for Git Large File Storage](https://help.github.com/articles/billing-plans-for-git-large-file-storage/).

Note: [issue 784](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/pull/784) I mentioned in the comments now (August 12th, 2016) refers (by the OP) to [AppVeyor "How to download file"](http://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/download-file), following the comment:

> I'm guessing using on of those approaches to download the `git-lfs.exe` would work just fine.
>
> I'm not aware of not being able to use `git lfs` in an appveyor itself.
>   I would imagine all you REALLY need to do is:
>
> - Download the `git-lfs.exe` file and unzip (I'm guessing something like this would help with that, I'm not a powershell genius)
> - Put `git-lfs.exe` in your path (dealers choice on how)
> - Run `git lfs install`.
>
> And then you can use `git lfs` to do everything you need (`git clone`, `git fetch`, etc...)

Comment: I'm not seeing this as being compatible with Appveyor:
https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/288
https://github.com/github/git-lfs/pull/784

Comment: @Daryl Yes, I suspect some kind of wrapper is needed to manage the interaction with Appveyor. The point of the answer is: right now, when it comes to store *large* volume of data in a Git repo, Git-LFS is the standard for now.

Comment: Except my question is how to still allow AppVeyor builds, so your answer, although a valid answer for the first part of my question, is not a valid answer for the entire question.

Comment: @Daryl I agree, though it was more about "can access these files" ;) When it comes to *access*, LFS is interesting as you can store big files anywhere you want, and still access them later.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed here:

http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/questions/1815-add-git-lfs-support-to-default-build-images

> Hi Kyle,
>
> Git LFS has been deployed to default build image.
>
> -Feodor

Is your issue solved?

Comment: I'll look at that.  If it works, I'll award you the bounty

Comment: I've been unable to research this, but did discover that if I zip my file, it is only 8mb, so I'll just do that and skip the whole Git LFS.  Your link has the best possible solution so I'm awarding you the points.